# <area> style changes are not being set through Jquery in mozilla

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I have a slider panel which provide user options and the the panel gets activated every time i hover over an image.

For that purpose i have used `<area>` in my HTML over the image.

Problems i am facing:

since i have handle it for all resolutions and window width i tried to set my coordinates of my image map through jquery on document.resize

this is what i am trying to do in jquery

```
$('#area1').attr('coords',"'" + (imgWidht-100) + ',0 ,' + (imgWidht) + ',' + 1200+ "'" );
```

This thing works completely fine with all the other browsers but in Mozilla every time it encounters the above statement it activates the slider panel on the whole image and not those particular coordinates.

Comment: Could you share your HTML code related with the element which has "area1" as id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('#area1').attr('coords', (imgWidht-100) + ',0 ,' + (imgWidht) + ',' + 1200 );
```